# What does B.D means in a Doctor's Prescription?

Tags: practice-of-medicine, oral-health, prescription

I searched the Web and I came across this article explaining the meaning of B.D it says that B.D means twice a day but it doesn't specifies that I have to take the medicine twice a day before or after meal, I mean after/before breakfast and dinner?

Comment: If a prescription says twice daily and there are no further instructions about taking with or without food or at certain times, then it doesn't matter. Just take the doses roughly 12 hours apart whenever it's most convenient for you.

Comment: *bis in die*? Neither your doctor nor your apothecary/drugist/dispenser explained that to you? – Well, as you already found out, 2x it is, but prescriptions aren't as exhaustive as what the doctor/pharmacist or PIL of your meds should say. What do they say?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As **@LangLangC** pointed out, *bis in die* is Latin for twice a day.

However, usually drugs come with a prescription information a bit more elaborate, and twice a day is more commonly abbreviated as B.I.D.

[image: Example Prescription]

This example and further examples can be found [here](http://www.ncpanet.org/pdf/students/2013/educators/appendixa.pdf).

In this example, p.o. (*per os*, latin for through the mouth) means oral consumption, and b.i.d (*bis in dies*, twice a day) twice daily. It is not specified if the intake should be before meal (a.c. or *ante cibum*) or after meal (p.c. or *post cibum*).

Your pharmacist should have provided you with more information about intake when you received your drugs.

You can find a list of medical abbreviations for prescriptions [here](http://www.d.umn.edu/medweb/Modules/Prescription/Abbreviations.html).